# PHP-MySQL-Dialog

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, dialog

Eu estou fazendo uma página, onde tenho um banco mySQL conectando com PHP.

O que eu queria é o seguinte, tenho um formulário com:  `pais(combo); nome(text);empresa(text)`, e quero que:

1. Quando deixar de completar algum dos campos, ele me informe que
   devo **preencher todos os campos**;
2. Se os campos estiverem preenchidos ele deverá validar se é um registo duplicado e mostrar o nome em questão; Ex.: "O *João* já foi cadastrado!"

Porém eu queria que ele me mostrasse esses alertas no Dialog do Bootstrap. É possível fazer isto?

Comment: O que você já tentou?

Comment: Você pode fazer isso usando a janela Modal, você já tem o PHP que faz a verificação se há registro duplicado e insere?

Comment: Sim você pode usar jquery validar os campos e ajax para verificar se existe o registro, se sim no retorno você terá a resposta se sim ou se não e ai é só usar o modal par a exibição da menssagem

Comment: Andre, Sim eu faço a verificação se já tem registro com o php. Eu queria apenas mostrar no Dialog o resultado.

Comment: Rodrigo, Voce teria um exemplo, ou script fácil para compartilhar. Sou novo com php, estou aprendendo lendo os fóruns rs. Obrigado

Comment: Por questões de segurança acho que deve validar também no server-side

Answer (score 0):

Só adaptar par seu uso mais segue um exemplo pratico.

///Código PHP

```
    $campEmail  = $_POST['campEmail'];

    // faz consulta no banco
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email ='".$campEmail.";
    $consulta = mysql_query($sql);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($consulta);

if(count > 0){
    while($linhas = mysql_fetch_array($consulta)) {
        echo $linhas["Nome"];
    }
}
else{
    echo "";
}
```

///Código Jquery

```
function buscarUsuario() {
        var email    = $("#cmpEmail").val();

        if (email != "" && email != undefined) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "./buscar.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {campEmail: email },
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != "") {
                       $('#modalConfirm').modal('show');
                       $('#msgRetorno').text("O usuário " + data + " já foi cadastrado!");
                    }
                    else {
                       $('#modalConfirm').modal('show');
                       $('#msgRetorno').text("Não existe na base!");
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    throw "Ocorreu uma falha ao verificar a estabilidade do funcionário, tente novamente.";
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            $('#modalConfirm').modal('show');
            $('#msgRetorno').text("Preencha todos os dados!");
        }
    }
```

///Código Html Modal

```
      <div class="modal fade" id="modalConfirm" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p id="msgRetorno"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Esse código não tem nenhum risco de SQL Injection não? O.o

Comment: Tem este código completo Rodrigo? Aqui montei mas não rolou =/ ..